# creating a full triangle including white space

Tags: javascript

I'm an intern developer, got a small exercise to do, which involves creating a triangle/pyramid with "*".

i can get as far as right angled and inverted too.. just cant seem to include the white space starting from the left of the page.

would appreciate it if anyone has some help on this.

My code is as follows:

```js
for (i = 0; i >= 5; i++) {
  for (j = (-2 * i); j <= i; j++) {
    if (j > i) {
      document.write(" ");
    } else {
      document.write("*");
    }
  }
}
```

End result im trying to get at:

```
     *
    * *
   * * *
  * * * *
 * * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<script>
for(i=0; i<5; i++) 
{  
        for(k=3; k>=i; k--)
        {
          document.write("&nbsp;"); 
        }
        for(j=2; j<=i*2; j++) {   
                 document.write("*");   
         }
        document.write("<br>"); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Or this one.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<script>
for(i=0; i<5; i++) 
{  
        for(k=4; k>i; k--)
        {
          document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;"); 
        }
        for(j=2; j<=i*2; j++) {   
                 document.write(" * ");   
         }
        document.write("<br>"); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function pyramid(size, hit, miss) {
  if (size === void 0) {
    size = 10;
  }
  if (hit === void 0) {
    hit = '▲';
  }
  if (miss === void 0) {
    miss = ' ';
  }
  var str = "";
  var currSize = size;
  while (currSize--) {
    var row = "\n";
    for (var a = 0; a < size * 2; a++) {
      if (a > currSize && a < size * 2 - currSize - 2) {
        row += hit;
      } else {
        row += miss;
      }
    }
    str += row;
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(pyramid());
```